# Java Desktop file download

Tags: java, desktop-application, netbeans-platform

While making a desktop application,I want it to be able to download a video file from server and save it in client's PC.
How to do it?I have no idea.
What tools to use?Please guide
I am looking forward to some kind of integrated FTP like thing.I am not clear how it will work.

Comment: The easiest way is probably with `URLConnection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you wanna download the file? direct url or youtube like?

Something like that:

```
public class DownloadToFile
{
    private URL from;
    private String to;

    public DownloadToFile(URL url, String path_to)
    {
        this.URL = url;
        this.to = path_to;
    }

    public DownloadToFile(String url, String path_to)
    {
        try
        {
            this.URL = new URL(url);
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.to = path_to;
    }

    public void saveFile() throws IOException 
    {
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(this.from.openStream());
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(this.to);
            try 
            {
                final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    int count;
                        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
                        {
                            out.write(data, 0, count);
                        }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (in != null)
                {
                    in.close();
                }
        if (fout != null)
        {
            fout.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Video File has to come from Vimeo

Comment: Have a look at:
http://jetcracker.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/vimeo-direct-download-link-java/

Comment: I have tried axet/vget and the code you gave.Axet/Vget 1.5 is not working on vimeo and it gives null pointer exception.
The code you gave at the link http://jetcracker.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/vimeo-direct-download-link-java/ is only producing the download link from a video link....How  to download a file from this link?

Comment: Do you have GSon? Import java.net.* .The VimeoDownloadLinkProvider is give the code for mobile. Change the remove "m/" from VIDEO_LINK_PREFIX and change MOBILE_QUALITY and SD_QUALITY to get better.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/hbok4m2bg8i78y4/VimeoDownloader.zip this will work but u will need gson.